# java.io.IOException: Stream closed (from groovy)

Tags: groovy, process

In groovy I am trying to run two calls to git using `Process` with:

```
def fireCommand(String command) {
  def proc = command.execute()
  proc.waitFor()
  println "Process exit code: ${proc.exitValue()}"
  def result = proc.in.text
  println "Std Err: ${proc.err.text}"
  println "Std Out: ${proc.in.text}"
}


def executeOnShell(String command) {
  fireCommand("git --version")
  fireCommand("git status")
}
```

But only the first call works. The second call throws:

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

From what I understand I am NOT reusing the same process so why the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `inputStream.text` or `inputStream.getText()` method, input stream is closed before method returns result - content of the stream (as String). So when you called

`println "Std Out: ${proc.in.text}"`

it tried to read from the same stream that already been closed.

```
println "Std Out: $result"
```

will be OK.